# Neighborhood search

Tags: python

I'm working on a 2-echelon vehicle routing problem (2E-VRP) and I'd like to use the neighborhood search base heuristic:

1. I wonder what's the difference between variable neighborhood search (VNS), large neighborhood search (LNS) and Adaptive large neighborhood search (ALNS).
2. Can I define more than one destroy operator in LNS? If yes, should I use all of them in sequence at each iteration or just select one of them randomly?
3. Also in ALNS, all the destroy operators used at each iteration or one of them selected base on its score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly speaking, search neighbourhood means the different solutions that are reachable by a move or search iteration. I believe variable neighbourhood search systematically increases the search neighbourhood when the solution appears to be stuck in local optimium (i.e. makes the neighbourhood bigger when a small neighbourhood isn't doing anything), whereas large neighbourhood search has a fixed but large search neighbourhood (i.e. neighbourhood size doesn't change). Adaptive large neighbourhood search would have multiple possible neighbourhoods corresponding to different search operations - e.g. different destruction or construction heuristics - and would try to learn which neighbourhood is best.

> Can I define more than one destroy operator in LNS? If yes, should I
>   use all of them in sequence at each iteration or just select one of
>   them randomly?

I suspect just choosing a single one randomly will be more effective.

> Also in ALNS, all the destroy operators used at each iteration or one
>   of them selected base on its score?

ALNS would select one based on its score, but you'd presumably still need to have a non-zero probability of selecting any operator for the adaptivity to work (as you'd need to be testing all operators once in a while).